# Is C# a viable language for a major project?

Tags: c#, c++, programming-languages, comparison

I've been using C# for a while now and I love it for its great integration with Windows. The Win32 API in C++ is a monster, but that's another story. Anyway, I was wondering, is C# a "good enough" language to use for larger projects? Does Microsoft use C# in any of their applications? I've always assumed C++ was the only choice for large projects because of its speed and has no need for the CLR.

What is your opinion on C#?

EDIT: By large I mean applications like Microsoft Project (first example that came to my mind). It could also mean mission-critical applications, as well.

Comment: define 'larger project'?

Comment: +1 - I agree with Marko's point that you should define "large" but as you're new to asking Qs on SO, I don't think you deserve the down vote...

Comment: I'd say scalability is a problem that every developer wishes they had... If you're genuinely expecting to have billions of transactions or inputs/second (eg large MS website/Google/etc.) then you may need to come up with something exceptional - For 99% of us, thousands of transactions/second is likely to be sufficient - so unless you're as popular as YouTube, scalability shouldn't be your *prime* concern - Remember that *good enough* really is just that - **good enough**. Get something that works for V1 and just make sure that V2 is better...

Comment: **It depends** upon application/project, of course -- not just "size". There are many functional requirements that .NET/C# may not be able to meet well (or at all). But the same goes to any other language and implementation: *You can't (or, really ought not to) pick out the socket/driver/hammer/shotgun until you know what you'll be doing.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you're after extreme performance (eg gaming), C# is perfectly acceptable for almost any application - I've been developing enterprise-scale apps in it for years and as a general rule, the advantages far outweigh any (negligible) performance losses compared to C++ - especially when you factor in development time and the relatively low cost of improving CPU speed.

Since I've started using C#, it would take a VERY good reason to make me go back to something lower-level like C++ - There are simply so many advantages in terms of ease of development, memory management, a huge library (.Net framework), [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), etc.

I would personally consider C# before any other language when starting a new project

Comment: I agree 100%, I just wanted to note that under extreme performance there is all kind of video tools, e.g. Pinnacle TV is written with .NET, and it's horribly slow on Windows. On Linux, Kaffeine does the same, but is a hell of a lot faster because it is written in C++, and that on the very same computer [dual booting]). So I wanted to remark that while performance loss on low performance programs is negligible, the performance loss is definitely not negligible for every kind of application.

Comment: @Quandary Very true - and I'd also say that certain apps require more manual memory management (think Photoshop) but if you're dealing with those sorts of requirements, you usually need specialist or highly skilled developers to do it right...

Comment: That's true, and while I am at it, all CD burners written in C# I've seen also don't work, for whatever reason. But I'm a .NET developer myselfs ;-)) It's however very good for writing a quick UI and function-rich business applications, which is what it is meant for.

Answer (score 3):

I've using c# since it came out and so far there were only a few things I couldn't do with it such as print drivers. Other than that I developed fairly complex multithreaded server-side applications that are both reliable and fast.

Also - you may want to define "large".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I'd encourage you not to follow a Vendor Lock in pattern. Although you could argue that doesn't really apply to .net, but you would lose.

Comment: +1 interesting point of view - I agree on your point re: vendor lock-in but at the end of the day, it'v _very_ hard to avoid especially in an enterprise environment

Comment: Java, Sun vs Microsoft, they are the lesser of two evils, I think.

Comment: 10 hours ago... you mean Oracle vs. Microsoft [Sun was bought by Oracle explicitly for sueing Google over Java in Android] (btw. .NET works quite well on Linux [and FreeBSD], where it's called mono). For developing, (.NET) you still need windows, however.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint and Dynamics (Microsoft products) (and several others) are written almost exclusively in .NET (C#). They would certainly be considered large, enterprise scale applications. Almost all internal project at Microsoft, with the exception or Windows and Office supposedly are written in C# these days (I think it's even a requirement for new projects).

Comment: Also of note: StackOverflow and FogBugz are both implemented in ASP.Net (presumably with C#). There is also a long list here: http://www.microsoft.com/net/casestudies/

Comment: technically FogBugz is implemented in their (FogCreeks) own language called Wasabi... speak of double standards attacking the Not-Invented-Here Syndrome, but i guess not everything applies when you're Joel Spolsky :) :)

Comment: @Pauli to be fair, Joel gets a lot of leeway in my book as his blog saved me many, many issues over the years :)

Answer (score 1):

You will incur larger startup times, as you have to load the .NET runtime.  Other than that, performance is actually quite good for most things.

And with the garbage collection, memory leaks are less of an issue, so Java and C# both become good options for mission-critical applications (memory leaks grow over time, and can kill things that run for weeks or months at a time.  With a more reliable memory footprint, you application can be more stable).

so... yes.